# Spring dependency injection and method local variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a for loop inside a method from where I create multiple instances of my class. However, I still need all the advantages of spring DI and AOP; however I could not find a way to inject the dependency inside the method. The only way I could do is get it with,
MyClass controller=(MyClass) context.getBean("myClass"); 
from the context. Is there an alternative ?

Comment: It seems that your way to build your "multiple instances" is not correct, so probably there is a different (correct) view to do what you need: probably it is better to review the whole workflow. Even if - thanks to some hammer hits - it's always possible to stick a cube in a round hole :) Anyway, you can mark your class as \@Component then inject services/beans via \@Autowired (but why... a controller?)

Comment: O sorry, it is not a controller, I provided an ambiguous sample, and I don't have web context at all. Just a simple class.

Comment: So please, let me resume. Do you want to inject a bean inside a method? Do you use Spring? If you don't use Spring, probably just a \@Inject is enough to have a bean at your disposal, but - I'm sorry - IMHO your question is still unclear :/